# {fmt}: Will a named argument be ignored if it doesn't exist in the formatting string?

Tags: c++, fmt

The following code compiles just fine and produces the string "abc":

```
fmt::format("abc", fmt::arg("x", 42));
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/8M79vnhqW)

So it looks like named arguments that are missing in the format string are just ignored.

My question is: **Is that by design or is it a bug**?

I'm asking because I'm having a use case for this "feature". So I want to make sure that this is neither UB nor that it will be "fixed" in future.

I already skimmed through the [docs](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html) but couldn't find this use case.

Comment: FWIW that's pretty consistent with how other languages handle that type of behavior, for example in python `print('abc'.format(42))` will also just output `'abc'`

Comment: As long as the call matches the signature of the called function (kind of a requirement for the code to build, after all), all unused arguments will simply be unused. It will work similarly to a function that defines a certain set of arguments, but leaves them unnamed (anonymous) in the actual function definition, which means the arguments are simply not used.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format `It is not an error to provide more arguments than the format string requires`, but that is for `std::format`. Research `fmt` github issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design. Unused formatting arguments are essentially the same as unused arguments to any other function and are not an error. This is the case in {fmt} and Python's `str.format` it is modeled after as well as `printf`.

Comment: An answer from the author himself must be correct, I guess :)